# Understanding Parameters - Changing & Using New Value On The Fly

Tags: ros, getparam, parameter-server, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS.  I am using Python 3 and ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.  I need help understanding parameters.

Currently, I use a launch file to set parameters and in the C++ publisher code I do a [getParam](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server)
to get the value of the parameter from the Parameter Server.  This works fine.

Now, I want to create a rqt GUI and from the GUI change the value of a parameter, get the new value in the publisher code and act on it, without restarting the Parameter server or publisher.

Can I do this with setParam() and getParam()?  I've read some about [dynamic_reconfigure](https://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).  Is that what I need to use rather than setParam()/getParam()?

Any help getting me started in the right direction is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396913/understanding-parameters---changing-&-using-new-value-on-the-fly/) by [Green01](https://answers.ros.org/users/92901/green01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to change parameters values during the node execution then yes dynamic_reconfigure is what you are looking for. Moreover you have the package [rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure) creating the GUI for you.

You should check [#q175010](https://answers.ros.org/question/175010/server-parameters-vs-dynamic-reconfigure/) comparing server parameters and dynamic reconfigure.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2022-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Green01](https://answers.ros.org/users/92901/green01/) on 2022-03-01**:
Thanks for the feedback. That is a helpful link to the question comparing server parameters and dynamic reconfigure as I hadn't found that question in my searches.